# Como descobrir o local de instalação de um pacote via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

Eu instalei um pacote como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$ apt-get install nome-pacote
```

Mas não consigo encontrar em qual diretório ele foi instalado. Existe algum comando para descobrir o local onde o pacote está?

Lembrando que se eu chamar o pacote ele funciona  normalmente, exemplo:

```
$ nome-pacote
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/apt-get-install-where-does-it-go) do site [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) você pode usar o comando `dpkg` com o parâmetro `-L`, assim:

```sh
dpkg -L <nome-do-pacote>
```

E para ver onde está o código-fonte:

```sh
apt-get source <nome-do-pacote>
```

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando [which](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29) ou [whereis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whereis).